# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/Vessels-Detection-10/train/00000742_jpg.rf.f14a935bb2e280f6b6e3474673251b7f.xml.xml'

Tags: xml-parsing, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I try to define my class to load my custom dataset in pytorch.

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
import cv2

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.images = []
        self.labels = []

        # Load the images and labels into the list
        for filename in os.listdir(root_dir):
            image_path = os.path.join(root_dir, filename + '.jpg')
            label_path = os.path.join(root_dir, filename + '.xml')

            image = cv2.imread(image_path)

            tree = ET.parse(label_path)
            root = tree.getroot()
            objects = root.findall('object')
            labels = []
            for obj in objects:
                bndbox = obj.find('bndbox')
                xmin = int(bndbox.find('xmin').text)
                ymin = int(bndbox.find('ymin').text)
                xmax = int(bndbox.find('xmax').text)
                ymax = int(bndbox.find('ymax').text)
                labels.append([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])
            
            self.images.append(image)
            self.labels.append(labels)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image = self.images[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        
        return image, label
```

But I get the following error:

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
53
54 # Create the dataset
---> 55 train_dataset = CustomDataset(root_dir='/content/Vessels-Detection-10/train', transform=transform)
56 test_dataset = CustomDataset(root_dir='/content/Vessels-Detection-10/test', transform=transform)
57 val_dataset = CustomDataset(root_dir='/content/Vessels-Detection-10/valid', transform=transform)

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py in parse(self, source, parser)
582         close_source = False
583         if not hasattr(source, "read"):
--> 584             source = open(source, "rb")
585             close_source = True
586         try:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/Vessels-Detection-10/train/00000742_jpg.rf.f14a935bb2e280f6b6e3474673251b7f.xml.xml'

I tried to remove the .xml extension from the label_path:
`label_path = os.path.join(root_dir, filename)`

But in vain:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 55, in 
train_dataset = CustomDataset(root_dir='/content/Vessels-Detection-10/train', transform=transform)

File "", line 22, in **init**
tree = ET.parse(label_path)

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1202, in parse
tree.parse(source, parser)

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 595, in parse
self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)

File "", line unknown
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0`

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem some times ago and I remember I had to add a dot at the start of the path for it to work.
So if your path is "/content/etc..."
Make it "./content/etc..."

Comment: If I add a dot, I get an error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './content/Vessels-Detection-10/train'

Comment: Might be a dumb question but are you sure the file/folder exist then? Isn't there any typo whatsoever?

Comment: Yes absolutely sure. The problem is that my files name end with .xml and not .xml.xml as you can see in the error